# DB2 Logic Apps connector - update row

Tags: db2, azure-logic-apps

I need to update a particular record in a DB2 table thanks to the DB2 connector of Logic Apps.
I have the id of the row and I only want to update several fields (not all fields).
My table has something like 100 fields. In the designer, all fields are set as mandatory, it means I need to set values for those fields but I don't want to.
Is there anything to do to indicate to the connector that I want to pass "null" values to avoid updating several fields?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the connector doesn't support this feature currently. The DB2 connector just support limited features, maybe it's because DB2 is not microsoft service. For this feature, you can raise a ticket on azure [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps) page to ask azure team to support.